# How to know, in the client, that an OAUTH completed succesfully server-side

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, oauth, openid-connect

Disclaimer: I'm a novice as far as client/server, webdevelopment and oauth is concerned.

I have to integrate against an OAuth-like backend that, upon success, returns a userId.
So I currently do something like

1. from the client, call a firebase cloud function
2. from the cloud function, I initiate the OAuth by calling a function offered by the backend

```
<oauth-domein>/oauth2/authorize/?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_url={redirect_url}...
```

- Within this call, the credentials of the user are asked and are redirected to us

3. in the redirect (another cloud function), we will

- request an OAuth access token (another call to the backend)
- with this access_token, we can request information on the user (like userId)
- we can check whether this userId exists and if not, we can create one using

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
admin.auth().createUser({uid: uid})
```

4. **At this point, we have a User in firebase and I would like to let the client side know that the OAuth succeeded.**

For other sign-in methods (email/password, facebook, OpenID Connect), the client is notified of `userChanges` (I'm using Dart)

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges().listen((User? user) {...});
```

So ideally, I would also like to trigger this userChanges-event from the firebase cloud function. But how can I do this?

I guess I have to authenticate the userId in firebase (which will trigger the userChanges-event I guess). I was trying to do something like

```
      const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
      admin.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken);
```

But there doesn't seem to be a `signInWithCustomToken` in admin.auth().

So I have the following questions

- can I trigger the userChanges() event from within a firebase cloud function (which is probably the same question as "can I authenticate a known userId in a firebase cloud function")
- if the answer to the above question is 'no': how can I notify the client that the OAuth was succesful?

bonus question: I would like to make this backend OpenID Connect compliant since that is supported out of the box by Firebase.  Any pointers on what is needed to do so?

Comment: Since you call the Cloud Function from the client (so it is an HTTPS or a Callable Cloud Function), you should be able to send back the result of the Cloud Function processing to the client. Also, note that you cannot trigger the `userChanges()` event from within a Cloud Function.

Comment: PS: The standard flow in your case (generating the JWT tokens on your own server) is described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) in the doc.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks for your input. The initial call can take up quite some time (~1 minute, depending on how long it takes for the user to enter his credentials).  Is it good practice to have such a long https connection?  I assumed it would be better/cleaner to have a short initial call followed by an event (if possible obviously).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to understand what you mean by "The initial call can take up quite some time (~1 minute, depending on how long it takes for the user to enter his credentials)". You should initiate the call to the Cloud Function only once the user has entered all the data necessary to create the JWT. *To be cont.* .../...

Comment: *.../... cont*. The doc details the flow: "You must create a server endpoint that accepts sign-in credentials—such as a username and password—and, if the credentials are valid, returns a custom JWT. The custom JWT returned from your server can then be used by a client device to authenticate with Firebase (iOS+, Android, web)." From what I understand from your question, in your case the "server endpoint" is the HTTP/Callable Cloud Function which in turns contact your "OAuth-like backend"

Comment: The backend that I have to integrate with, asks for the credentials so I don't have to ask them.  This is similar to eg a Facebook integration (or Google or OpenIDConnect) where I initiate the sign in and then a (Facebook) popup appears asking for my credentials.  If all goes well, I get a `userChanges` event at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A schema detailing the flow you're trying to implement would help a lot.

Comment: I've updated the flow in the question: hopefully, this makes things clearer (and thank you once more for taking your time to trying to help me here!)